# leetcode subsets II bug?

Tags: c++, subset

working on subset II (find subsets of a collection of numbers with possible duplicates). My code

```
class Solution {
public:
vector<vector<int>> subsetsWithDup(vector<int>& S) {
    sort(S.begin(),S.end());
    vector<vector<int>> allSets;
    vector<int> sol;
    allSets.push_back(sol);
    int c=0;
    S.push_back(S[S.size()]+1);
    for (int i=0;i<S.size()-1;i++){
        if (S[i]==S[i+1]) {
            ++c;
            continue;
        } 
        int n=allSets.size();
        if (c>0){
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            sol=allSets[j];
            for (int k=0;k<c+1;k++){
                sol.push_back(S[i]);
                allSets.push_back(sol);
            }
        }
        c=0;
        } else {
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            sol=allSets[j];
            sol.push_back(S[i]);
            allSets.push_back(sol);
        }
        c=0;
        }

    }

    return allSets;
}
```

};

when test case is [1,1], it returns [[]], instead of [[],[1],[1,1]]. where is my bug?

Answer (score 0):

turns out
S.push_back(S[S.size()]+1); 
should be S.push_back(S[S.size()-1]+1);